# Unable to find code where crash happens in xcode crash report

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash-reports

I got several crash reports in x-code(reported by users) but unable to find out what is it for. I opened it in project but it doesn't show me code line where crash occurred (obviously i tried clicking on every line of the stack trace).

[image: stack trace from x-code]

Comment: What happening on console?

Comment: this crash report is from actual user (not from developing process)

Comment: @Parth, do you test the crash with `All Exceptions`?

Comment: sorry @aircraft i didn't get your question

Comment: @Parth, `All Exception` breakpoint, i mean, have tried with this?

Comment: @aircraft this crash report is reported by users, so i can not make break points

Comment: there is usually a slider at the bottom of the stack trace in your screen shot, move it around to reveal more of the trace, if you havent done so already

Answer (score 5):

If you want to trigger Crashes in your released builds so you should integrate crash reporter in your project and **`Crashlytics`** is one of them.

[Integrate Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)

Integrate it and release your build to client or tester. Whenever it will crash you will be notify by email with the Name of controller with line number.

**If you are Debugging:**

You must use `Exception Breakpoint` for this:

In your `Project Navigator` Select `Breakpoint` and `Select + Option` like below:

[image]

Ater that you will prompt with :

[image]

It will automatically `Enable Exception Breakpoint`.

Comment: @Parth have a look to my answer above.

Comment: Yes....  
Exception break point only works while debugging. If your app is in release mode then you must integrate Crash Reporter. Crashlytics is one of them and easy to integrate.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4025082/sandeep-singh-rana :)